# Blameshifting from self to another

Tags: single-word-requests, pejorative-language

Looking for a word that means accusing someone else of what you are guilty of.

Comment: So you are making them the **scapegoat** for your actions??.......I don't know if *scapegoating* is a real verb or not.

Comment: [Related](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/4732/word-for-disrespecting-eldest-half-sister-by-referring-to-her-husband-as-girly-g#comment16076_4732).

Answer (score 2):

*Projecting* or [projection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Psychological_projection) is the psychological name. Again at a psychological level, a person who lashes out rather than accept blame can be called *defensive*.

Comment: The OP didn't really specify so it may not matter but I was curious...  isn't projection done at a sub-conscious level?

Answer (score 2):

Consider "**[buck passing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buck_passing)**" for blameshifting from **self** to another.

> **[pass the buck](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/pass+the+buck)**: to blame someone or make someone responsible for a problem that you should deal with yourself.

"*Never one to admit his errors, he [**passed the buck**](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/pass+the+buck) to his colleagues.*"

Comment: *Passing the buck*, rather.

Comment: @choster "buck passing," rather.

Comment: I can't seem to understand the downvote here. Would the person clarify why?

Answer (score 1):

It's not specific to yourself, but you can make someone a [*scapegoat*](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/scapegoat).

> 1. a person or group made to bear the blame for others or to suffer in their place.

Also used as a verb

> 1. to make a scapegoat of: *Strike leaders tried to scapegoat foreign competitors*.

Answer (score 1):

It is a recognised psychological attitude called:

**Playing the Blame Game**

If something has gone wrong (or is not the way it should be), then someone other than myself must be identified and blamed for causing the situation.
[the blame game](http://www.psychologytoday.com/blog/what-would-aristotle-do/201207/stop-playing-the-blame-game)